# Not able to get the cover , profile photo to display in screen

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3

I am currently working on facebook login app.And i am trying to display user cover photo and user profile pic.

But here i was not able to pic the cover, profile photo and not able to populate in my image views.

**here my code :**

```
   func getFacebookGraphAndSegue(token:String) {

        guard let req = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"email,name, first_name, last_name,id,cover,picture.width(100).height(100)"], tokenString: token, version: nil, httpMethod: "GET") else {
            print("could not get Facebook user info")
            return
        }
        req.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) in
            if(error == nil) {
                print("result \(result)")
                guard let userInfo = result as? [String: AnyObject] else {print("bad result");return}

                let name = userInfo["name"] as? String ?? ""

//                let cover = (userInfo["cover"] as? UIImage!)["source"]{
//                    var coverUrl = cover as?  String
//                    
//                }
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "loginSegue", sender: userInfo)
            }
            else {
                print("error \(error)")
            }

        })

    }




  //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MARK: - Segue


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "loginSegue" {
            if let vc = segue.destination as? UserViewController {
                if let info = sender as? [String: AnyObject] {

                    let email = info["email"] as? String ?? ""
                    let name = info["name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let firstName = info["first_name"] as? String ?? ""
                    let lastName = info["last_name"] as? String ?? ""

                    let lbl:String = "\nNAME:\(name)"
                    print(lbl)
                    vc.info = lbl

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the commented line in above function is i tried to get the cover photo as well as profile pic and below i need to display.

In my next screen only  i will display user name, profile pic,cover photo :

```
 @IBOutlet weak var labelUserInfo: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var coverpageImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profilePicImage: UIImageView!

    var info:String = ""

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.labelUserInfo.text = info
    }

    @IBAction func onLogout(_ sender: UIButton) {
        //Facebook Logout
        print("on Facebook Logout Tapped")
        let loginManager = LoginManager()
        loginManager.logOut()
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "logouSegue", sender: nil)
    }
```

please help me out. How can i get the cover , profile pic to display in my screen / image view.

thanks

Comment: I think the issue is here `let cover = (userInfo["cover"] as? UIImage!)["source"]`because you can not cast directly to UIImage. You should cast it first to Data and then generate a new CGImage and then a UIImage. I have not used the FB SDK to get an image, but maybe what you get is the URL of the image so you should call the `UIImage(from url:)` method then.

Comment: I dont know how to do that...i searched more..but not able to get. Thats why asked help in so

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38556649/6203030